# ¿Cómo comprobar que una cadena de texto está comprendido entre 0 y 7 sin convertir a entero?

Tags: java

Tengo que comprobar que la cadena introducida por el usuario sea un número octal, para ello tiene que estar entre 0 y 7, de lo contrario tengo que avisar al usuario que el dato introducido no se convertirá.

El problema es que no puedo convertir a entero, ni usar excepciones ni throws.

Hasta el momento:

1. Pido el dato al usuario: Ok.
2. Limpio la cadena de espacios: Ok.
3. Valido la cadena: Error.

   ```
   // Variables necesarias
   Scanner pedirDato = new Scanner(System.in);
   String trim;

   // Se pide al usuario que ingrese un número octal
   System.out.println("Introduce un número octal: ");
   String cadena = pedirDato.next();

   // Limpiamos la cadena eliminando espacios anteriores y posteriores
   trim = cadena.trim();

   for (int i = 0; i < trim.length(); i++) {

       StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
       c.append(trim.substring(i, i + 1));

       System.out.println(c);

       if(c.equals("0")) {

          //esoctal = true;

           System.out.println("Es un octal válido " + c.toString());

       } else {

           System.out.println("No es un octal válido: " + c.toString());
       }

       c.delete(0, i);

   }
   ```

Tengo que comprobarlo, según los requerimientos, usando un bucle y extrayendo y comprobando cada carácter de la cadena.

Y lo que he intentado es eso, genero un bucle for hasta la dimensión de la cadena introducida, y luego quiero comprobar si está entre 0 y 7.

He empezado sólo validando el 0, pero el programa me devuelve que 0 no es un octal válido usando `equals`. ¿Por qué?

> Para la prueba 0001111 me devuelve:

```
Introduce un número octal: 
0001111
0
No es un octal válido: 0
0
No es un octal válido: 0
0
No es un octal válido: 0
1
No es un octal válido: 1
1
No es un octal válido: 1
1
No es un octal válido: 1
1
No es un octal válido: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios errores o detalles a tener en cuenta

Salvo que por algun motivo quieras guardar la cadena original, no tiene ningun sentido hacer:

```
// Limpiamos la cadena eliminando espacios anteriores y posteriores
trim = cadena.trim();
```

Mejor hacer:

```
cadena = cadena.trim();
```

Porque usar un stringbuilder para ir guardando los pedazos de tu cadena uno a uno? es como si no supieras para que sirve el stringbuilder. El mismo se usa cuando vas a construir cadenas muy grandes. Si para colmo, vos vas a borrar el contenido, no sirve para nada, mejor usar una variable string solamente.

Y como si fuera poco, stringbuilder.equals no compara el contenido de las cadenas (ver [aca](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) y [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18565731/73749)) compara si son la misma instancia del objeto.

Lo mejor seria que te sacaras de encima el stringbuilder, y usaras un string

```
for (int i = 0; i < trim.length(); i++) {
    String c ;
    c = trim.substring(i, i + 1));
    System.out.println(c);
    if(c.equals("0")) {
       //esoctal = true;
        System.out.println("Es un octal válido " + c.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No es un octal válido: " + c.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, efectivamente me he liado con el stringbuilder yo solo, cuando la solución era muchísimo más fácil. Es lo que tiene empezar con java.